# My QGIS plugin shows GUI but not Works. How to get Error log?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am new to PyQgis. I made a simple calculator with PyQt4, now I am trying to run it under QGIS. I connected calculator as plugin, and tested it, its GUI works without error but it does not calculates anything.

How can I get error log?

**calculator.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from calculate_ui import Ui_Dialog
from math import *
from qgis.core import *

def derece(degrees):
    return degrees*((2*pi)/400)

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, iface):
      QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
      self.iface = iface
      self.setupUi(self)
      self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)
      # Validations
      tempValidator = QtGui.QDoubleValidator()
      tempValidator.setNotation(QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
      self.ui.at.setValidator(tempValidator)
      self.ui.Rt.setValidator(tempValidator)
      # Signal/slot connections.
      self.setupConnections()

    def calc(self):
      a = float(self.ui.at.text())
      R = float(self.ui.Rt.text())

      T=R*tan(derece(a/2))
      L=(2*pi*R*a)/400
      BS=(R/cos(derece(a/2)))-R

      self.ui.Tt.setText(str(T))
      self.ui.Lt.setText(str(L))
      self.ui.BSt.setText(str(BS))
    def silk(self):
      self.ui.at.clear()
      self.ui.Rt.clear()
      self.ui.Tt.clear()
      self.ui.Lt.clear()
      self.ui.BSt.clear()

    def setupConnections(self):

      self.connect(self.ui.hesaplak, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
          self.calc)
      self.connect(self.ui.temizlek, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
          self.silk)
```

You can take a look at the plugin from [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3SF155iRQSEfkN6NGhFQlZtd1luSDlGMFRFc0ZRRkFpUUFiUndiVUVaQkFNdEVVT2V3T0k&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

Python messages can be printed to the python console.

This is accessed from *Plugins> Python Console*.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your connections are wrong.

Remove your `setupConnections` function, and connect them under `__init__`:

```
self.ui.hesaplak.clicked.connect(self.calc)
self.ui.temizlek.clicked.connect(self.silk)
```

I guess your `derece` function also should be inside the class (then call it with self.).

Comment: Unfortunately the code [link](http://pastebin.com/d0iPs9ha) didnt work again. Thank you.